# Marking row/column as dirty so that can be returned using .getChangedCells('dirty')

Tags: jquery, jsp, jqgrid

Is there any way to force a JqGrid row/col data as 'dirty'?

Whenever I check for `.getChangedCells('dirty')`, I want to add an additional row which is not modified, so it will not be returned using this method.

All I want is to mark a row/col data dirty forcefully so that whenever I call this method it will return me that row as well.

My jqgrid data is :

```
var mydata = [      
    {id:"1",blkNo:"101",floorNo:"04",unitNo:"184",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"",dateAborted:"",unitStatus:"Draft",saleInd:0,propertyType:1,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"2,"blkNo:"101",floorNo:"04",unitNo:"184",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"",dateAborted:"",unitStatus:"Draft",saleInd:0,propertyType:1,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"3",blkNo:"101",floorNo:"04",unitNo:"184",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"",dateAborted:"",unitStatus:"Draft",saleInd:0,propertyType:1,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"4",blkNo:"101",floorNo:"04",unitNo:"185",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"",dateAborted:"",unitStatus:"Submitted",saleInd:0,propertyType:1,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"5",blkNo:"101",floorNo:"04",unitNo:"186",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"",dateAborted:"",unitStatus:"Submitted",saleInd:0,propertyType:2,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"6",blkNo:"101",floorNo:"04",unitNo:"187",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"",dateAborted:"",unitStatus:"Submitted",saleInd:0,propertyType:3,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"7",blkNo:"101",floorNo:"04",unitNo:"188",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"",dateAborted:"",unitStatus:"Submitted",saleInd:0,propertyType:3,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"8",blkNo:"101",floorNo:"04",unitNo:"189",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"2011-05-10",dateAborted:"2011-05-15",unitStatus:"Submitted",saleInd:1,purchaserDtail:0,propertyType:0,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"9",blkNo:"101",floorNo:"04",unitNo:"190",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"2011-05-10",dateAborted:"2011-05-15",unitStatus:"Submitted",saleInd:1,purchaserDtail:0,propertyType:0,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"10",blkNo:"101",floorNo:"05",unitNo:"191",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"2011-05-10",dateAborted:"2011-05-15",unitStatus:"Submitted",saleInd:1,purchaserDtail:1,propertyType:1,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"11",blkNo:"101",floorNo:"05",unitNo:"192",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"2011-05-10",dateAborted:"2011-05-15",unitStatus:"Submitted",saleInd:1,purchaserDtail:2,propertyType:2,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"12",blkNo:"101",floorNo:"05",unitNo:"193",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"2011-05-10",dateAborted:"2011-05-15",unitStatus:"Submitted",saleInd:2,purchaserDtail:2,propertyType:2,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"13",blkNo:"102",floorNo:"01",unitNo:"183",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"2011-05-10",dateAborted:"2011-05-15",unitStatus:"Submitted",saleInd:2,purchaserDtail:1,propertyType:1,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"14",blkNo:"102",floorNo:"02",unitNo:"184",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"2011-05-10",dateAborted:"2011-05-15",unitStatus:"Submitted",saleInd:2,purchaserDtail:0,propertyType:0,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"},
    {id:"15",blkNo:"103",floorNo:"03",unitNo:"183",area:"1000",streetName:"Peck Seah Street",interested:"Yes",price:"3000000",pricePSF:"3000",dateofLaunch:"2011-05-05",dateofSale:"2011-05-10",dateAborted:"2011-05-15",unitStatus:"Submitted",saleInd:2,purchaserDtail:0,propertyType:1,leastPrice:"200000",leastPricePSF:"200"}
];
```

This is my `getModifiedRows` method:

```
function getModifiedRows() {
    var allRowsInGrid = $('#list4').jqGrid('getRowData');

    for(j=0; j< allRowsInGrid.length;j++) 
    {
        if( allRowsInGrid[j]['unitStatus'] == 'Draft')
        { 
            var rowId = allRowsInGrid[j]['id'];   
            $('#list4').addClass("dirty-cell");     
            $("#list4").jqGrid("setCell", rowId ,'pricePSF' ,'', "dirty-cell");
        }
    }

    var retRows = $('#list4').getChangedCells('all');
    var retCol = $('#list4').getChangedCells('dirty');
    var entireGrid = $("#list4").jqGrid('getGridParam','colNames');

    if(retCol != '' && retRows != '')
    {
        alert(retCol);
        for(i=0; i< retCol.length;i++)
        {
            var obj = retCol[i];
            obj['row_Index']= retRows[i]['row_Index'];
            obj['unitStatus']= retRows[i]['unitStatus'];
            obj['pricePSF']= retRows[i]['pricePSF'];
            alert(retRows[i]['unitStatus']);
            if(retRows[i]['unitStatus'] == 'New')
            {
                retCol[i] = retRows[i];
            }
        }
        var modColData = JSON.stringify(retCol);    
        var modRows = JSON.stringify(retRows);
        document.getElementById("getGridData").value = modRows;
        document.getElementById("getModColData").value = modColData;
    }
}
```

Though I don't get any error from this code, I don't get this row inside below code:

```
var retCol = $('#list4').getChangedCells('dirty');
```

As it's clear in getModifiedRows, I want every unit with `unitStatus = Draft` to be returned in

```
var retCol = $('#list4').getChangedCells('dirty');
```

I can see the value getting changed if I pass any hard coded value for this column like:

```
$("#list4").jqGrid("setCell", rowId ,'pricePSF' ,'200', "dirty-cell");
```

But I'm still unable to retrieve it inside modified

```
var retCol = $('#list4').getChangedCells('dirty');
```

This is my `colNames` and `colModel`:

```
colNames:['S No','Block No','Floor No', 'Unit No', 'Street Name',' 6- Digit Postal Code' ,'Trans Id','Address','Property Type','Area (sqm)','Date of Option Issued','Nett Transacted Price ($)','Gross Transacted Price ($)','Transacted Unit Price ($psf)','Nationality Of Buyer','Interested Party Transaction','Date of Option Aborted','Unit Status','listPriceFilter','salePriceFilter','sale_Date_Filter','aborted_Date_Filter','row_Index'],
//column no [1    2           3          4          5              6              7         8         9               10      11            12            13            14                        15                         16                               17                 18           19              20                      21              22                     23
colModel:[
    {name:'id', index:'id', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
    {name:'blkNo', index:'blkNo', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"text", sortable:true, editable:true, editrules:{custom:true, custom_func:mandatoryChk}}, 
    {name:'storey', index:'storey', align:"center", width:40, sorttype:"text", sortable:true, editable:true,  editrules:{custom:true, custom_func:storeyCheck}},    
    {name:'unit_No',index:'unit_No', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"text", editable:true, editrules:{custom:true, custom_func:checkUnit}, onblur: 'submit'},
    {name:'street_Name', index:'street_Name', width:60, align:"center", sorttype:"text", editable:true, editrules:{required:true}},  
    {name:'postal_code', index:'postal_code', width:60, align:"center", sorttype:"text", editable:true, editrules:{custom:true, custom_func:postalCode}},  
    // {name:'postal_code', index:'postal_code', width:60, align:"center", sorttype:"text", editable:true, editrules:{custom:true}},  
    {name:'trans_Id', index:'trans_Id', width:60, align:"center", sorttype:"text", editable:false},  
    {name:'address', index:'address', width:60, align:"center", sorttype:"text", editable:false},  
    {name:'property_Type', index:'property_Type', align:"center", width:80, sortable:true, editable:true, edittype:"select", editoptions:{value:pptyTypeStr}, formatter:'select', stype: 'select'},                 
    {name:'area', index:'area', width:50, align:"center", sorttype:"integer", editable:true, editrules:{custom:true, custom_func:myAreaCheck, number:true, required:true}},
    {name:'sale_Date', index:'sale_Date', align:"center", width:75, sorttype:"date", sortable:true, editable:true, editoptions: {
        dataInit: function (element) {
            $(element).datepicker({
                dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy",
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                    var $input = inst.input; // the datepicker input
                    var $row = $input.parents("tr"); 
                    $("#list4").jqGrid('saveRow',$row.attr("id"), false); 
                }
            });
        }
    }},  
    //  {name:'nett_Price', index:'nett_Price', width:80, align:"center", sorttype:"currency", formatter: 'currency',formatoptions: {  thousandsSeparator: ", " , decimalPlaces: 0, defaultValue: ''  }, editable:true , editrules:{custom:true, custom_func:mynettpricecheck , number:true} },    
    {name:'nett_Price', index:'nett_Price', width:80, align:"center", sorttype:"text", editable:true, editrules:{custom:true, custom_func:mynettpricecheck }},
    // {name:'sale_Price', index:'sale_Price', width:80, align:"center", sorttype:"currency", formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: {  thousandsSeparator: ", " , decimalPlaces: 0}, editable:true ,editrules:{custom:true, custom_func:mypricecheck,number:true}},
    {name:'sale_Price', index:'sale_Price', width:80, align:"center", sorttype:"text", editable:true},
    {name:'pricePSF', index:'pricePSF', width:80, align:"center", sorttype:"text", editable:false},
    {name:'nationality_Code', index:'nationality_Code', width:80, align:"center", editable:true, sortable:true, edittype:"select", formatter:'select', stype: 'select', searchoptions:{
            sopt: ['eq'],
            dataInit: function(el){
                var defOption = $("option:contains("+defaultCategory+")",el);
                defOption.attr("selected", "selected");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(el).trigger('change');
                },500);
            }
        },
        sorttype: function(cell, obj) {
            return purchaserDtail[cell];
        },
        editoptions:{value:purchaserDtailStr}
    },          
    {name:'interested', index:'interested', align:"center",width:70, sortable:true, editable:true, edittype:"select", formatter:'select', stype: 'select', editoptions:{value:interestedStr}},
    {name:'dateAborted', index:'dateAborted', align:"center", width:75, sorttype:"date", sortable:true, editable:true,
        editoptions: {
            dataInit: function (element) {
                $(element).datepicker({
                    dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy",
                    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                        var $input = inst.input; // the datepicker input
                        var $row = $input.parents("tr"); 
                        $("#list4").jqGrid('saveRow',$row.attr("id"), false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },
    {name:'unitStatus', index:'unitStatus', align:"center", width:60, sortable:true, editable:false},
    {name:'listPriceFilter', index:'listPriceFilter', align:"center", width:40, editable:false},
    {name:'salePriceFilter', index:'salePriceFilter', align:"center", width:40, editable:false},
    {name:'sale_Date_Filter', index:'sale_Date_Filter', align:"center", width:40, editable:false},
    {name:'aborted_Date_Filter', index:'aborted_Date_Filter', align:"center", width:40, editable:false},
    {name:'row_Index', index:'row_Index', align:"center", width:40, editable:false, key:true}
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just add `"dirty-cell"` class to the cells (`<td>` elements) which you want mark as "dirty". You can use for example [setCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method to add the class to the cell specified by rowid and the column name:

```
$("#yourGridId").jqGrid("setCell", rowid, "columnName", "", "dirty-cell");
```

**UPDATED**: You formulate your question in a wrong way. The method `getChangedCells` works only together with [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing). Every cells editing in cell editing mode get `"dirty-cell"` class after saving of the cell modifications. The rows get additionally `"edited"` class. The method `getChangedCells` uses the fact.

The code of which you later posted show that you use [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) method which is part of [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing). You can't mix cell editing and inline editing in one grid.

You don't posted full code which you use. So it's unclear for me which editing mode you want to use. If you do want to use cell editing then you should modify your code to use [saveCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#methods) instead of [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow). Additionally if you need to mark some cell as "dirty-cell" you will need to mark the row as

```
var $grid = $("#yourGridId");
$($grid[0].rows.namedItem(rowid)).addClass("edited");
$grid.jqGrid("setCell", rowid, "columnName", "", "dirty-cell");
```

or

```
var $grid = $("#yourGridId");
$("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid)).addClass("edited");
$grid.jqGrid("setCell", rowid, "columnName", "", "dirty-cell");
```

After that you will be able to use `getChangedCells` method.

If you do want to use inline editing instead of cell editing you will not able to use `getChangedCells`, but you can enumerate rows (`<tr>` elements) which has `editable` attribute. The class will be added to all rows which was edited. If the value of the attribute is "1" then the row is editing now and you have to call [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) method to save the changes. If the value of the attribute is "0" then the row was edited before and can be interpreted as "dirty". Rows which has no `editable` attribute was not edited with respect of inline editing.

Comment: Thanks 

I did as above, but could not retrieve this row by using 

 var retCol = $('#list4').getChangedCells('dirty');

when i display this variable, it gives value only if i modify any row in jqgrid, else it will not display anything.
i am using jquery and JSON any suggestions on this..

i am modifying my current row using

$("#list4").jqGrid("setCell", j , "columnName", "", "dirty-cell");

and retrieving using  

 var retCol = $('#list4').getChangedCells('dirty');

i am very new to this jquery stuff.. please point out if its not correct way

Thanks a lot

Comment: @checkgdata: You are welcome! You should append your question with JavaScript code which you use. You should include at least one row of test data which you use to fill the grid. Is `j` in your case really the `id` of the row which you need to modify or it's the row number? Do you replaced ` "columnName"` to the name of the column from `colModel`?

Comment: Thanks for your time...!

I have replaced correct column name, but j is the row which satisfies condition for which i want to set row as modified. 

var allRowsInGrid = $('#list4').jqGrid('getRowData');
    for(j=0; j< allRowsInGrid.length;j++)
    {
   
 
      if( allRowsInGrid[j]['unitStatus'] == 'Draft')
     {
     $("#list4").jqGrid("setCell", j , pricePSF, "", "dirty-cell");
      
     }
     
    }
is it correct? how do i retrieve rowid here?

after this var retCol = $('#list4').getChangedCells('dirty');

doesnt display the modified row.

Thanks

Comment: @checkgdata: You are welcome! Could you **append the text of your question** with additional information (click on "edit" link below the text of the question)? How variable `pricePSF` is defined? It's important to know how you define rowid in your data. The usage of `j` could be wrong. How you fill the data of the grid? Could you provide more full code with data which can be used to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi Oleg, I used
 $("#list4").jqGrid("setCell", 5 ,'pricePSF' ,'121', "dirty-cell");
just to check if value is changed or not, every time i change value, changed value is displayed but still i can not retrieve this unit inside 

 var retCol = $('#list4').getChangedCells('dirty');

any idea? why!
Thanks

Comment: can you share anything on this?

Comment: @checkgdata: You don't posted the most important thing: the code which shows how you create jqGrid. You posted code of the function `getModifiedRows`, but it's not clear when (in which context) you use the code. Other HTML elements like `getGridData` and `getModColData` are other undefined. So I can't reproduce the problem based on the information which you posted.

Comment: i can't append complete code as it was too long so i just pasted grid.

Comment: i dont understand one thing, i can see changed value in jqgrid using $("#list4").jqGrid("setCell", 5 ,'pricePSF' ,'121', "dirty-cell");
i can see this new value 121, but still not able to retrieve it inside $('#list4').getChangedCells('dirty'). this is really fooling me

Comment: do you require anything more to this? i am badly stuck, not able to find any solution for this

Comment: anything on this, i could not find any solution.

Comment: @checkgdata: Sorry, I forget about your question. I reread it after your last modifications and posted "**UPDATED**" part of my answer.

Comment: can i email you my code as its too long, i am not allowed to post it here

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it finally worked. So sorry for all the confusions i created.. ill b clear next time on.. thanks much

Comment: can you help me on my other question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238613/jqgrid-filter-and-drop-down#comment21487079_15238613